# Extend Ally of AdonisJS with Bitly

Tags: oauth-2.0, adonis.js

I use AdonisJS v4 and I want extend Ally, the auth extension of AdonisJS.

`this._getAccessTokenUrl()` parse `this._baseSite + this._accessTokenUrl`

But the endpoint URL of Bit.ly is **https://bitly.com/**, the authorize URL is **oauth/authorize** and the access token URL is **https://api-ssl.bitly.com/oauth/access_token**

```
  /**
   * Base url to be used for constructing
   * google oauth urls.
   *
   * @attribute baseUrl
   *
   * @return {String}
   */
  get baseUrl () {
    return 'https://bitly.com/'
  }

  /**
   * Relative url to be used for redirecting
   * user.
   *
   * @attribute authorizeUrl
   *
   * @return {String} [description]
   */
  get authorizeUrl () {
    return 'oauth/authorize'
  }

  /**
   * Relative url to be used for exchanging
   * access token.
   *
   * @attribute accessTokenUrl
   *
   * @return {String}
   */
  get accessTokenUrl () {
    return 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/oauth/access_token'
  }
```

Authorize URL will be: https://bitly.com/oauth/authorize
And Access Token URL will be (*incorrect*): https://bitly.com/https://api-ssl.bitly.com/oauth/access_token

It's impossible to add Bitly in provider of Ally, could you help me please?

Comment: Can you override `_getAccessTokenUrl()` for your bitly ally provider class?

Comment: I would like to do it but I do not know how "override"...

Comment: Overriding a class method is really easy in JavaScript. Just define the method on your class. If the parent class had that method, you just overrode it!